# How to parameterise a command invocation inside a script block?

Tags: powershell, syntax, parseexception, scriptblock, unexpected-token

I am trying to write a PowerShell script with a Script Block that is to be passed to Invoke-Command. The script block needs to invoke an executable whose path is determined by a PowerShell variable ($bar in this example)

However, when I try to do this, I get the following exception:

```
At C:\Users\foo\test.ps1:4 char:13
+ $cmd3={$bar "param"}
+             ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '"param"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

test.ps1 consists of these lines:

```
$bar="foo.exe"
$cmd1={foo.exe "param"}
$cmd2={$bar}
$cmd3={$bar "param"}
```

It seems a variable $bar can be used, but only if there are no arguments (cmd2). A literal foo.exe can be used even if there are arguments (cmd1)

I want to use a variable reference for the executable name and more than 0 arguments (cmd3), but this case is not allowed, it seems.

Why?

Comment: *inside a script block* Does this part actually matters? Did you get any different result if you just write `$bar "param"` without wrapping it in script block?

Comment: @PetSerAl - yes, you are correct. This is not an issue with script block's  per se, but with the PowerShell command invocation syntax in general. 

You suggested answer above contained the solution. Specifically I need to declare the command as `& $bar "param"` or the script block as `{& $bar "param"}`

Thanks for your help!